# Background picture in Green Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

I have a very simple question. On the Green Shoes website one can read that it is possible to set a image as the background of a app (cf. http://ashbb.github.io/green_shoes/Background.html). However I have tried it but it does not seem to work.

```
background black  #Works

image "my_pict.jpg"  #Works

background "my_pict.jpg"  #Does not work
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

> background url(/path/to/image/my_pict.jpg);

Comment: What you pass as an argument? can you paste your code here?

Comment: background url(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/My_pic.jpg")